# How to remove empty columns in 2D Array in Javascript efficiently

Tags: javascript, arrays, csv, multidimensional-array, data-structures

I have following array of arrays (2D Array)

```
Input    csvData = [["", "2", "",  ""], ["", "3", "", ""], ["", "", "4", ""]]
```

How to remove empty columns from above array.

```
   Output   csvData = [[ "2", ""], ["3", ""], ["","4"]]
```

I am trying but not able to complete.

```
  removeEmptyColumns(csvData) {
    for (let i = 0; i < csvData.length; i++) {
      let col = csvData.map(function (value, index) { return value[i]; });
      for (let j = 0; j < col.length; j++) {
        if (col[j])
          break;
      }

    }

  }
```

Comment: I would consider the slice method (https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_array.asp) for efficiency and maintainability.

Comment: Why does the second column stays in the output matrix?

Comment: only the first cell in each row is empty.

Comment: I don't understand, shouldn't the output be: `csvData = [[ "2", ""], ["3", ""], ["", "4"]]`?

Comment: Yes @ibrahimmahrir  .. my mistake.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir Could you please try my another complex problem here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55083788/2d-array-complex-alignment-in-javascript

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could get first the filled column and then filter the arrays.

```js
var csvData = [["", "2", "",  ""], ["", "3", "", ""], ["", "", "4", ""]],
    columns = csvData.reduce(
        (r, a) => (a.forEach((v, i) => r[i] = r[i] || v), r),
        []
    );

csvData = csvData.map(a => a.filter((_, i) => columns[i]));

console.log(csvData);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

For deleting only the last empty columns, you could get the max value of the filled columns and delete the rest.

```js
var csvData = [["", "2", "",  ""], ["", "3", "", ""], ["", "", "4", ""]],
    max = csvData.reduce(
        (r, a) => (a.forEach((v, i) => v && (r = Math.max(r, i))), r),
        0
    );

csvData = csvData.map(a => a.slice(0, max + 1));

console.log(csvData);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: What is the time complexity for the above answer? Is there any edge cases it can fail?

Comment: at least O(2n).

Comment: could you please solve my another complex problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55083788/2d-array-complex-alignment-in-javascript

Answer (score 2):

Use `Array.reduce()` with `Array.some()` to identify empty columns.

Then use [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to iterate the array, and [`Array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to remove the items at the empty columns.

```js
const removeEmptyColumns = arr => {
  // detect empty columns
  const emptyColumns = (arr[0] || []).map((c, i) => arr.some(a => a[i]))
  
  // filter empty columns
  return arr.map(a => a.filter((_, i) => emptyColumns[i]))
}

pp(removeEmptyColumns([["", "2", "",  ""], ["", "3", "", ""], ["", "", "4", ""]]))

pp(removeEmptyColumns( [["1", "2", "", "4"], ["", "3", "", ""], ["", "", "", "2"]]
))

function pp(d) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(d))
}
```

Comment: Droi, Could you please try to solve my another complex problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55083788/2d-array-complex-alignment-in-javascript