# Find zero index data in 2d Array Javascript

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, ecmascript-6, underscore.js, lodash

Get all 0 index data in 2d array javascript

```
let a = [["", "2", "", ""], ["1", "3", "", ""], ["", "", "4", ""]]
index = 0

output = ["", "1", ""]
```

Similarly get all remaining index data

```
index= 1
output = ["2", "3", ""]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the first index:

```
const result = Array.map(a=>a[0]);
```

result will contain the first index of all the elements in the nested array. This works by iterating through the array and fetching the first index elements

Comment: Could you please try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55083788/program-to-2d-array-complex-alignment

Answer (score 2):

You can use [**reduce**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

Loop through arr and for each element in arr loop through to get the desired index value and push it to op.

```js
let a = [["", "2", "", ""], ["1", "3", "", ""], ["", "", "4", ""]]

function getIndex(arr,index){
  return arr.reduce((op,inp) => {
    let val = inp.find((e,i) => i === index )
    op.push(val)
    return op
  },[])
}

console.log(getIndex(a,0))
console.log(getIndex(a,1))
```

Comment: Could you please try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55083788/program-to-2d-array-complex-alignment

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method with [ES6 destructuring feature](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment). Destructuring helps to extract certain property from an object(Javascript Array is also an object).

```js
let a = [
  ["", "2", "", ""],
  ["1", "3", "", ""],
  ["", "", "4", ""]
];
let index = 0;

let output = a.map(({[ index ]: v }) => v)

console.log(output);


index = 1;

output = a.map(({[ index ]: v }) => v)

console.log(output);
```

Comment: Could you please try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55083788/program-to-2d-array-complex-alignment

Comment: @SreekanthReddy sure let me check

Answer (score 1):

With lodash you can just use the index as an iteratee:

```
const result = _.map(a, 1);
```